# Getting loader issue to parse ag-grid/angular.css file in Angular 15 upgrade

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I got this build error, while upgrading Angular 14 to 15.

I tried adding css loader, but didn't work

```
./node_modules/@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css?ngGlobalStyle:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .ag-icon {
|   font-family: var(--ag-icon-font-family);
|   font-weight: var(--ag-icon-font-weight);
```

**package.json** - A part of it

```
{ 
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "^27.3.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^31.0.1",
    "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^31.0.1",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^31.0.1",
    "@ag-grid-community/styles": "^31.0.1",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^23.2.1",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "^28.2.1",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export": "^31.0.1",
 "ag-grid-angular": "^31.0.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^27.3.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^27.3.0",
    .
    . and more 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue with `cropperjs`

```
./node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css:11:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

With Angular 14 I found the workaround thru `angular.json` file :

```
...
    "styles": [
        "src/styles.scss",
        "node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css"
    ],
...
```

but this workaround doesn't work anymore

---

[EDIT]

I've found the solution for my issue, may help for yours ?
In the component I was importing the css file witch doesn't seem necessary anymore

```
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';
// import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';

@Component({
...
```

Compiling goes thru now !